# How to list buildpacks on cloudfoundry

Tags: cloud-foundry

I know that we can deploy our applications through pivotal cloud foundry.We can push build packs that provide framework and run time support for your applications.I want to create a Jenkins job to list all the build packs available on my cloud foundry.How this can be achieved.Thanxx

Comment: Also see https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/ and child pages

Answer (score 6):

You can use the CLI to list the buildpacks: `cf buildpacks` or you can just query the cloud controller directly (api.`system domain`) by GETing `/v2/buildpacks`, however you need to be an authenticated user to make this request.

Answer (score 0):

Even more you can launch curl directly from cf client command:

```
# cf curl /v2/buildpacks
{
   "total_results": 9,
   "total_pages": 1,
   "prev_url": null,
   "next_url": null,
   "resources": [
      {
         "metadata": {
            "guid": "b7890a54-f7c5-4973-a3da-e1a48ba6811d",
            "url": "/v2/buildpacks/b7890a54-f7c5-4973-a3da-e1a48ba6811d",
            "created_at": "2017-05-24T12:53:27Z",
            "updated_at": "2017-05-24T12:53:27Z"
         },
         "entity": {
            "name": "binary_buildpack",
            "position": 1,
            "enabled": true,
            "locked": false,
            "filename": "binary_buildpack-cached-v1.0.11.zip"
         }
      },
...
         "metadata": {
            "guid": "95e3f977-09d1-4b96-96bc-e34125e3b3a2",
            "url": "/v2/buildpacks/95e3f977-09d1-4b96-96bc-e34125e3b3a2",
            "created_at": "2017-05-24T12:54:03Z",
            "updated_at": "2017-05-24T12:54:04Z"
         },
         "entity": {
            "name": "staticfile_buildpack",
            "position": 8,
            "enabled": true,
            "locked": false,
            "filename": "staticfile_buildpack-cached-v1.4.5.zip"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Doc https://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/258/